# Android jetpack compose theme switch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm having trouble adding a theme switcher to the Profile Screen, allowing users to choose between an automatic theme (device theme), dark theme, or light theme. I've tried multiple approaches and spent 5 days on this problem, but I haven't found a solution that works for my case. I also searched for documentation on this issue but couldn't find any with detailed explanations that would work for me.

Here's the code I have so far:

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen(navController: NavHostController, profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
    Scaffold(
        content = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
            ) {
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Dark"
                    )
                    Switch(
                        checked = false,
                        onCheckedChange = {}
                    )
                }

                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Light")
                    Switch(
                        checked = false,
                        onCheckedChange = {}
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        bottomBar = {
            NavBar(navController = navController)
        }
    )
}
```

```kotlin
class ProfileViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    var isAutoThemeEnabled by mutableStateOf(true)
    var isDarkThemeEnabled by mutableStateOf(false)
    var isLightThemeEnabled by mutableStateOf(false)
}
```

```kotlin
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    // Dark theme colors
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    // Light theme colors
)

@Composable
fun RealtyDealTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorScheme
    } else {
        LightColorScheme
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        typography = Typography,
        content = content,
        colorScheme = colors
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set `RealtyDealTheme` as the root of all your composables.

```kotlin
fun ProfileScreen(navController: NavHostController, profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
    RealtyDealTheme(optionalBooleanToSetTheme) {
        Scaffold(...) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can add these lines in `RealtyDealTheme` to change navigation bar and status bar if you need it:

```kotlin
rememberSystemUiController().setStatusBarColor(
    color = if (darkTheme) DarkColors.background else LightColors.background
)
rememberSystemUiController().setNavigationBarColor(
    color = if (darkTheme) DarkColors.surfaceColorAtElevation(elevation = 2.dp) else LightColors.surfaceColorAtElevation(elevation = 2.dp)
)
```

Comment: Will it help if I have many screens?

Comment: @TheDavich Just wrap the screen parent of all screens so that any children at any depth will follow that color scheme.